# How do I get a reference to the currently displayed Java Swing JDialog box?

Tags: java, swing

I am using a Java Swing based framework that shows popup messages using Java Swing JDialog boxes. I need to get a reference the them so I cam close them programatically. The framework creates dialog boxes but doesn't keep a reference to them. Can I get a reference to the currently displayed box?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to find the reference of ALL Jdialog visible or only the one in the foreground?

Comment: checkout [ActiveWindowTracker](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/find_current_last_active_window) from my blog

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDialog d = new JDialog((Window)null,"Demo Dialog");
        for (Window w : JDialog.getWindows()) {
            if ( w instanceof JDialog) {
                System.out.println(((JDialog)w).getTitle());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you are puzzled by the :

```
(Window)null
```

cast, simply try to compile without it :)

(BTW passing a null window to the constructor creates an unowned dialog)

**EDIT: Please note that this will give you references to ALL dialogs regardless of whether they are visible as the code demonstrates. To fix it simply query the dialog on whether it is visible by using isVisible()**

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get a reference to the front-most JDialog, then you have to listen to AWT events and update this reference "live" and store it somewhere.

Here's what I do in my own Swing framework:

```
public class ActiveWindowHolder
{
    public DefaultActiveWindowHolder()
    {
        _current = null;
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener()
        {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
            {
                DefaultActiveWindowHolder.this.eventDispatched(e);
            }
        }, AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    public Window getActiveWindow()
    {
        return _current;
    }

    private void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.getID())
        {
            case WindowEvent.WINDOW_ACTIVATED:
            _current = ((WindowEvent) e).getWindow();
            break;

            case WindowEvent.WINDOW_DEACTIVATED:
            _current = null;
            break;

            default:
            // Do nothing (we are only interested in activation events)
            break;
        }
    }

    private Window _current;    
}
```

Just make sure you instantiate `ActiveWindowHandler` in your main thread before showing any component; from that point on every call to `ActiveWindowHandler.getActiveWindow()` will return the front-most Window (either `JDialog` of `JFrame`).

Comment: This is just great. :-)
Why do you set it to `null` when the `WINDOW_DEACTIVATED` event occurs?

Comment: @Kurtibert this can happen when the last window gets closed, hence there's no active window left.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to all of your child windows using getWindows() method on the Window class.

```
public static Window[] getWindows()

    Returns an array of all Windows, both owned and ownerless, created by this application. If called from an applet, the array includes only the Windows accessible by that applet.
```

Be carefull as I suspect one of the windows returned will be your top level frame/window.  You can check window attributes such as title to determine which is the dialogue you want to close.

There are also more specific versions: getOwnedWindows() and getOwnerlessWindows() depending on your needs.

Comment: Since 1.6, btw. Much better to use a sensible framework than trying to hack this.

Comment: When running in WebStart/PlugIn you might find that you get a dummy dialog as well in some situations.

Comment: @Tom, I agree about your framework/hack comment, but I suspect from the answer by Eugene that Dave has already been advised to correct the framework once already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to know what is currently open as a child of a frame - I only see methods for getting the parent frames.

Can you alter the current classes calling the dialog boxes?  If so, you could add a container to keep track of things as they open and close and add some methods for accessing that container.

Answer (score 0):

Window w = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusedWindow();

You can then check and cast it to JDialog.

But like I said in your previous question - you have to change your approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the `JDialog` explicitly rather than using `JOptionPane.showXXX` you will already have a reference to the dialog.  This would definitely be my preferred approach; e.g.

```
JDialog dlg = new JDialog(null, "My Dialog", false); // Create non-modal dialog.
dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
dlg.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
dlg.pack();
dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dlg.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: he probably wants the reference at some other/irrelevant part of the code. Therefor i proposed an answer that gives back references to all dialogs...

Comment: @Sawas: You're probably right but to be honest this sounds like bad design IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

either set the dialog as modal, which makes your life really easy...
OR, when you're initialising your JDialog have the following:

```
JDialog d = new JDialog();  
d.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
        dialogClosedAlertFunction(); //goes wherever you want it to go
    }
});
```